# How is source code of a high-level language converted into machine code?

Tags: compilation, code-generation, lexical-analysis

I am learning the compilation process within my college Computing course, and I understand the basic functions of three stages of compilation. (Semantic, Syntax and Lexical analysis). I do not fully comprehend what they do however. How does a high-level language such as python get converted into machine code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Extremely simple and generally speaking***: A compiler it often broken into a number of components, where each component transforms it's expected input into expected state of the next component until the target result is produced. The following is a basic high level path through those transformations:

1. Scanner - Reads and tokenizes the source file
2. Analysis - Is syntax corrected?
3. Parser - Generate AST from token form
4. Analysis - Are the constructs semantically correct?
5. Emitter - Generate machine code from AST

> Note: The steps can vary, modularization may vary, where symbol trees
>   are built may vary, the kinds of AST may vary, etc. so study these
>   areas independently.